# Wax to finish and smooth out dining tabletop with deep gouges

Tags: wood, wood-finishing

I have an old wood dining table which I would like to sand down and refinish. Unfortunately it has many deep gouges in it. I am hoping that there is some sort of wax finish that I can use that can also fill in these gouges. I am imagining that I can heat the wax to liquify it and let it fill in the gaps and harden... Does such a wax exist?

Ideally I would like to go with a natural entirely non-toxic product...

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Such a wax exists... but before we use it how deep xare these gouges? If you took a fork and dragged it deeply across a finished tabletop you could/would fill the damage with colored beeswax. Deeper gouges would necessitate different fillers, colored shellac sticks heated and melted into the holes works well. Typically, however, if you're sanding off the entire finish, you'd do that carefully and then look again at your problems. Sand only in dire straits..

Is the rest if the finish okay? Sanding destroys a good piece.. Proceed with great caution... do as little as possible. If it's just an ordinary thing - be careful here too - strip it gently, clean per instruction, seal with sanding sealer.. Adjust color, and THEN match a color. If its a good piece, there's a lot to know so you don't ruin it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I really appreciate it!  To answer the question, some of these gouges are quite deep (ex 1/2") while others are more modest. They are everywhere. I actually like the look of it and am not expecting or hoping for the wax to hide it in any way, just to smooth it out so that the surface is more usable/cleanable.